# Multiple For Loop Iterations (Combination) with filter to achieve highest possible value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of "Points" & it's "Value".
I want to get highest possible "Value" from combination of "Points".

Example:

**My Target Point: 100**

```
Point   Value
1       111
2       222
3       333
4       444
5       555
6       666
7       777
8       888
9       999
10      1110
11      1221
12      1332
13      1443
14      1554
15      1665
16      1776
17      1887
18      1998
19      2109
20      2220
```

There can be **TRILLIONS** of combination but I need only those *combinations upto "My Target Point" yielding Highest "Value"*.

***Possible Answers:***

**1. (Point 16)*2 + (Point 17)*4 = 100**

**(Value 1776)*2 + (Value 1887)*4 = 11100**

**2. (Point 1)*100 = 100**

**(Value 111)*100 = 11100**

**& so on.....**

So finally I need just one (any) combination with highest value.

```
amt2 = 0

For i20 = 0 To 5 ' (Max multiple -> 100/20 = 5)
For i19 = 0 To 5 ' (Max multiple -> 100/19 = 5)
For i18 = 0 To 5
For i17 = 0 To 5
For i16 = 0 To 6
For i15 = 0 To 6
For i14 = 0 To 7
For i13 = 0 To 7
For i12 = 0 To 8
For i11 = 0 To 9
For i10 = 0 To 10
For i9 = 0 To 11
For i8 = 0 To 12
For i7 = 0 To 14
For i6 = 0 To 16
For i5 = 0 To 20
For i4 = 0 To 25
For i3 = 0 To 33
For i2 = 0 To 50
For i1 = 0 To 100 ' (Max multiple -> 100/1 = 1)

point1 = (1 * i1) + (2 * i2) + (3 * i3) + (4 * i4) + (5 * i5) + (6 * i6) + (7 * i7) + (8 * i8) + (9 * i9) + (10 * i10) + (11 * i11) + (12 * i12) + (13 * i13) + (14 * i14) + (15 * i15) + (16 * i16) + (17 * i17) + (18 * i18) + (19 * i19) + (20 * i20))

If point1 <= 100 Then
amt1 = (111 * i1) + (222 * i2) + (333 * i3) + (444 * i4) + (555 * i5) + (666 * i6) + (777 * i7) + (888 * i8) + (999 * i9) + (1110 * i1 + (1221 * i11) + (1332 * i12) + (1443 * i13) + (1554 * i14) + (1665 * i15) + (1776 * i16) + (1887 * i17) + (1998 * i18) + (2109 * i19) + (2220 * i20)

If amt2 < amt1 Then
amt2 = amt1

<Save Combination Details>

End If
End If

Next i1
Next i2
Next i3
Next i4
Next i5
Next i6
Next i7
Next i8
Next i9
Next i10
Next i11
Next i12
Next i13
Next i14
Next i15
Next i16
Next i17
Next i18
Next i19
Next i20
```

Problem with my code is that it iterates through ALL possible combinations which takes lots of time & produce little result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Trillions" underestimates how much work your code is trying to do. Your code would pass through the innermost loop 1.94*10^21 times, which at the rate of 10 million passes per second (about the most VBA could give) would take over 6 million years. Instead, just use the [Solver add-in](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Load-the-Solver-Add-in-in-Excel-612926fc-d53b-46b4-872c-e24772f078ca) to solve what is a fairly straightforward [integer programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Set up your spreadsheet something like this:

[image]

Your data is in columns `A:B`, I added a new column of decision variables, a constraint cell in `D2`, and an objective function in `E2`.

The formula in `D2` is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A21,C2:C21)
```

and in `E2` it is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B21,C2:C21)
```

Then I simply ask the solver to find the maximum of cell `E2` by changing cells `C2:C21` subject to the two constraints that `D2 <= 100` and that `C2:C21` are integers. I keep the default setting that variables are assumed to be nonnegative, and tell the solver to use the Simplex method (which under the hood will use branch-and-bound for solving this ILP). The optimal solution according to the Solver (found in less than a second as opposed to 6 million years) is `10*Point1 + 6*Point15` with a total value of `11100` -- which happens to be a value that you have already found, showing that this problem has multiple optima.

It is possible but not easy to do this all in VBA, since the solver add-in can be invoked in code. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Functions/using-the-solver-vba-functions) for a basic introduction.

Comment: You,sir, are brilliant. It worked like a charm after I tweaked a little (`Integrity Constraints to 0%`). It saved me lot of time trying to write in VBA. Thanks a ton.